# What kind of rhyme is "pan" and "screen"?

Tags: rhymes

I know there're various types of rhyme in English, such as slant rhyme.
There're also things called assonance and consonance.

I plan to rhyme "pan" with "screen".

Essentially two monosyllabic words ending with "n".

Obviously this is imperfect rhyme at best.

Is there a linguistic term to describe this type of pairing?
If so, what is it called?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be tempted to call it consonance. But because the rhyme is so limited, even that's a stretch.

Comment: Welp, I was wrong. The [closest match on WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme) is indeed slant rhyme (aka half rhyme).

Comment: I would call it not a rhyme at all. I would only consider _pan_ and _screen_ to ‘rhyme’ if they were part of a sentence where **every** word ends in an n, as in “In Penn, ten fine men pan an’ nine then line the screen” or something (preferably something that makes a bit more sense, though).

Comment: I'm with Janus on this one. I'd call it ***assonance*** though, especially the example he gives.

Answer (score 2):

I think [pararhyme](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pararhyme) is close to what you are asking:

> - is a half-rhyme in which there is vowel variation within the same consonant pattern.

- "Strange Meeting" (1918) is a poem by Wilfred Owen, a war poet who used pararhyme in his writing. Here is a part of the poem that shows pararhyme:

> Too fast in thought or death to be bestirred.
>   Then, as I probed them, one sprang up, and stared
>   With piteous recognition in fixed eyes,
>   Lifting distressful hands, as if to bless.
>   And by his smile, I knew that sullen hall,
>   By his dead smile I knew we stood in Hell.

Comment: Thanks.  Essentially Wilfred Owen rhymed "stirred" with "stared".  I think "pan" and "pain" are pararhyme, but "pan" and "screen" are not quite.

Comment: I feel like "bestirred" and "stared" is pushing it.

Comment: @SimonKuang: It may seem like it, but recall that Owen was educated in Birkenhead, and in some of the local accents "stir" and "stare" are in fact pronounced similarly or identically.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is consonance, the repetition of consonant (not necessarily all consonants), which is "n" in my case.

Examples of consonance:

```
"weird", "blood"      (the repetition of the ending "d")
"reek" and "book"     (the repetition of the ending "k")
"pan" and "screen"    (the repetition of the ending "n")
```

Consonance + Assonance would get you full rhyme when you have two monosyllabic words, for example,

```
"flood" and "blood"
"rook" and "book"
"glean" and "screen"
```